# Different fonts for different weights in OpenOffice.org

Tags: fonts, openoffice, libreoffice

I want the default font to be Gentium, but its bold is incomplete, so I want bold and bold-italic to be Gentium Basic.  I want to have it set as the default font every time and not manually per usage.

How would I go about doing this?

I suppose this applies to LibreOffice as well.

Comment: Sounds like http://superuser.com/questions/302107/how-to-set-the-default-font-in-libreoffice-calc may be helpful here, too.