# How to set the default font in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: fonts, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, templates

How do you set the default font used in new documents of LibreOffice Calc? I am using LibreOffice 3.3.2.

Some answers below have been updated for LibreOffice 4 as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use the customized document as standard template (so it's used if you select menu `File -> New -> Spreadsheet`), the following steps are required (assuming you've  created a fresh spreadsheet document and changed the default font as Kirk has described):

- Select menu `File -> Templates -> Save...`;
  [image: Save File as Template]
- In the Template dialogue, enter a name for your template; make sure that "`My Templates`" is selected in the "`Categories`" list, then click `OK`.
  [image: Enter name and select Category for new Template]
- Select menu `File -> Templates -> Organize...`;
  [image: Open Template Organizer]
- In the template management dialogue, double-click on the "`My Templates`" entry in the list on the left; below "`My Templates`", a list of your templates should appear, among them the template you saved in step 2;
  [image: Set custom template as new default template]
- right-click on our template defined in step 2, select "`Set as default template`", close the template management dialogue.

That's it - now, if you create a new spreadsheet document, it should be based on your custom template.

EDIT 1:

For updated instructions based on LibreOffice 4, see [carnendil's answer](https://superuser.com/a/610511/84724)

EDIT 2:

[Setting a custom default template **doesn't affect CSV files** opened with LO Calc.](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86336) There are two workarounds:

- use csv2odf to create a new ods file from csv and name the Calc template to use explicitly (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13446079/342546);
- create a new ods file and "import" the csv data using Menu `Insert` -> `Sheet from File` or Menu `Insert` -> `Sheet` -> `from file` (see [this answer on Ask LibreOffice](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/27342/template-file-not-lauched-when-importing-from-csv-file/?answer=27367#post-id-27367)):

[image: Insert Sheet from File]

Comment: the screenshots are created using openoffice, but it's the same as in libreoffice (and even the same in openoffice / libreoffice writer).

Comment: You're instructions* worked for me when I create a new spreadsheet using File -> New.  However, when I open a CSV file and it creates a new document using the Text Import feature, it appears to NOT use the default template and still uses the PREVIOUS default font.  How do I get it to use the NEW default font, even when opening CSV files?  (*with only a few differences in LibreOffice 4.2.6.3)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue to @TylerRick, but when I add a new sheet to my spreadsheet. I open a new document (LibreOffice, by the way) and it comes up with my default style, but adding a new sheet uses the old style. Any ideas?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Sorry, i can't reproduce this using LibreOffice 4.2.7.2. If i create a new Spreadsheet file based on my custom template and add sheets using the (+) sign at the bottom (sheet tabs), ot using the menu (Insert -> Sheet), the new sheet has the same customized defaults as the first sheet. Did you insert existing sheets (Insert -> Sheet from File)?

Comment: @TylerRick: You're right, LO seems to ignore the custom default template when opening a csv file. I've edited my answer, pointing to two workarounds for this.

Comment: @TylerRick: see https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86336 - you may subscribe to that bug to receive updates by the LO developers.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Thanks for the workarounds and the bugzilla link!

Comment: So basically this answer doesn't answer the question. 1. it's a hack, and if you open csv file it default to some font. 2. why Libre calc default font is "Liberation Sans" and how to change it?, by default I mean "selected when calc is opened after installation". Now how to change it is the question?

Comment: +1 for an excellent tutorial. Nowadays, there is the *Save as Template* dialog with the *Set as Default Template* checkbox. The only caveat is that you must select a template category.

Answer (score 19):

Format menu -> Styles and formatting. You should get a dialog that looks similar to this:

[image]

Right click on Default, and choose modify. In the fonts tab you should be able to choose the new default font.

Comment: ... and of course, you can combine this answer with the @tohuwawohu answer to make the style change the default.

Answer (score 9):

Updated instructions for LibreOffice 4.0.x:

The process is still as per [tohuwawohu's answer](https://superuser.com/a/302133/217553), yet the specific steps have changed a little:

1. To save as template, go to menu **File** > **Save as template...**

   [image: libreoffice-menu-guardar-como-plantilla-r]
2. Select "My Templates" in the Template Manager, and then click on the button "Save". See image on the next step.
3. A new window will appear asking for a name for the new template. Give a descriptive name and click on the button "OK".

   [image: libreoffice-plantillas-guardar-mis-plantillas-nombre]

   <sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version.</sup>
4. Now go to menu **File** > **New** > **Templates**
5. Select the tab titled "Spreadsheets", double click on "My Templates" and select your newly saved template. Of a series of buttons that appear under the tabs, select the one labeled "Predeterminate" in order to set the template as the default for Calc.

   [image: libreoffice-calc-plantillas-predeterminar]

   <sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you have with other languages (Complex Text Layout (CLT) languages like Persian languages) just do this first:

1. Click on English/any default language on status bar and then select *More*.
2. Select your western and CTL font and default language you want.
3. For setting these configurations, just do same as [Kirk said above](https://superuser.com/a/302125/104400) to set this template as.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited to indicate that this is an answer rather than a comment]

The basic concept that the way to set a font (and other parameters) in LO Calc is to create an empty sheet with the appropriate settings and save it as a template, remains valid. However, the details vary from one version to another, and LO 5.2 has some subtle differences. The "Save as template" option has gone from the File menu; the "obvious" way of creating a sheet with desired settings, then Saving it As ODF Spreadsheet template (.ots) will produce a template file in a location specified by the user, but will not install the template as default.

For LO 5.2, in an empty sheet set the font with **Format -> Style > Styles and formatting (or just press F11), right-click Default, click Modify**, and make any desired settings (e.g., I prefer top alignment in addition to my chosen font). Then *do not Save As and select .ots*.

Instead: **File > Templates > Save as Template** (or Shift-F11) in the **My Templates category. Tick the "Set as Default Template" box** and give it a name (e.g. MyCalcStartupOptions, CalcTimesRoman) before saving. That finishes the process. ["Set as default" presumably gets rid of the need to set "predeterminate" in Templates Manager (which is now reached by **File > Templates > Template Manager** or Ctrl-Shift-N)].

If you ever need to find the file: **Tools > Options** (or Alt-F12) **> Paths > Templates**.

HTH

Comment: Please, don't post comments as answers. We understand that you might have some valuable information, but answer posts are only for actual answers to the question. [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)