# how do I set default formatting with openOffice?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openoffice, templates, libreoffice

I type a lot and i like to have the background black and the text a soft green or gray. I can see how to change the background and text color for one document but i would like to set this up as the default so when I open up a new document I can just start typing and dont have to make any adjustments. Anyone know how to save these settings? I cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've described this for [setting the default font in LibreOffice](https://superuser.com/questions/302107/how-to-set-the-default-font-in-libreoffice-calc/302133#302133) including Screenshots of every step. The same works for OpenOffice. In short:

1. Create a document containing the customized styles;
2. Save that document as template;
3. Set the document as standard template.

Comment: perfect does everything i need, opening the program fresh or opening a new document uses the saved template, thanks