# How to change the default font in LibreOffice 4

Tags: fonts, openoffice, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

How do I change the default font in LibreOffice / OpenOffice. So that when I open a new spreadsheet document it doesn't revert to use the standard default font (Liberation Sans/Serif)

[How to set the default font in LibreOffice Calc?](https://superuser.com/questions/302107/how-to-set-the-default-font-in-libreoffice-calc) Following the solution here only affects new document/spreadsheet created in LibreOffice / OpenOffice, where as, as Tyler Rick pointed out in the post the solution only affects new documents created within LibreOffice/OpenOffice not documents opened with it(LibreOffice).

Answer (score 1):

If the document you opened is styled, then you can't. Templates (thus fonts) are applied for newly created documents. It does not make sense for LibreOffice or any text processing program to override font styles of existing documents, because there might be multiple font styles used in the document, and it will most likely turn them ugly if it does so. Nevertheless, you can check each *used* style and change it, or try to change their parent style (Default), which is supposed to affect them all unless they were explicitly modified.

However, if you are opening a style-less format (e.g., *.CSV), then you can change it by clicking Styles Icon -> Default -> Font as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the help file:
You need to create a template with the attributes you desire. To change the font for the cells, do the following:

1. Press F11
2. Right click on Default
3. Select Modify
4. Click on Font tab
5. Select desired font
6. Click OK

If you want to change the font for the charts, you will need to change that as well.

Save the file as a template in C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\LibraOffice\4\user\template. Select File, New, Templates, select the tab for the file type, select the file you just saved and then Set as Default.