# Styling multiple files on Libre Office Calc

Tags: pdf, csv, libreoffice-calc

Here's what I do now:

1. Get CSV file from extrenal source
2. Open it in Calc
3. Apply style (set colors, fonts, etc.)
4. Export as PDF

Is it possible to get rid of step 3? Somehow loading data to already styled document?

Columns on different CSV files are always the same, but rows might have different data.

I am open to other alternatives too.

Comment: Maybe [this answer (scroll down to "EDIT 2")](http://superuser.com/a/302133/84724) is helpful for you?

Comment: @tohuwawohu Thanks for the link, I will read it and see if it works.