# Fixed column width for CSV files

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I use LibreOffice (6.1.6.3) Calc to work with CSV files.

Some of these files have very long text in their "cells". When I open such file in Calc, the Calc tries to make the column as wide as possible. It's like "Hey, you have very long text here, right? So, I will enlarge the column width to make your life easier." In my case it results to gigantic widths.

Instead, when I open such file in Calc, I would like to have the columns to be displayed at some fixed width, about 4 centimeters (1.5 inches). Is it possible?

Comment: No, currently not. It's a known bug since five years that LO Calc won't apply "custom default templates" when opening csv files - see https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86336 . With this bug fixed, you could create a custom default template with pre-defined column width. See also https://superuser.com/a/302133/84724 .

Comment: Thanks! (I will remove this comment later.)

Comment: @tohuwawohu Which office suite (or another app) is the best to edit CSV files from your point of view? I already tried German PlanMaker and Chinese WPS. The first one is very cumbersome in "open-save" parts. The second one doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: This is impossible to say, since it depends on the sepcific use case. If you want to follow the "spreadsheet" approach, you may giv Gnumeric a try. There are a lot of different options, e.g. editing csvs using LO Base.